# Trying to set a hook, but I get a "TypeError: is not a function"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui

Here is a code sandbox: https://ytppvr.csb.app/

I'm trying to use material UI's ToggleButton and changing the view the user gets depending on what button is clicked:

```
const [view, setView] = useState("view 1")

const handleViewChange = (value) => {
  console.log("this is the value", value.target.value)
  setView(value.target.value)
}
```

the jsx:

```
<ToggleButtonGroup
   value={view}
   exclusive
   aria-label="Platform"
   onChange={handleViewChange}
>

<ToggleButton value="view 1">View 1</ToggleButton>
<ToggleButton value="view 2">View 2</ToggleButton>

<ToggleButtonGroup>
```

A snippet of how the rest of the code looks like:

```
{view ==="view 1" ?
  (<div>
    <Grid container spacing = {2}>
      {view1_cards.map((card, index) => (
        <Grid item xs={6}>
          <Card key={index} title={card.title} content={card.content}>
            <CardContent>
              <h2>{card.title}</h2>
              <p>{card.content}</p>
            </CardContent>
          </Card>
        </Grid>
      ))}
    </Grid>
  </div>) :
  <div></div>
}
```

Basically, every view has its own set of cards to show.

When I click on any of the ToggleButtons I get

```
TypeError: setView is not a function
```

This is very similar to this one but even after making sure I do what OP was asked, I still get problems:

[useState hook giving "not a function" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67920005/usestate-hook-giving-not-a-function-error)

Comment: You have a ton of bugs in the code snippets that you provided (incorrectly closed tags, incomplete ternaries, etc). I suggest cleaning up the snippets and/or providing a CodeSandbox that reproduces the error.

Comment: You need to import the `useState` hook: 
`import { useState } from "react";` 

Then `setView("...")` will work.